# highcharts - add label for missing column

Tags: highcharts

In my chart, I have a column with a value of -1. This is to indicate that the value for this series is not available.

In the chart, I would like to add a label rotated 90 degrees that says "No data" where the bar should be. Can someone provide me with an example for how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please read 'How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example': https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a column with -1 it will still be rendered. You need to map -1 values to null. After that you can use [renderer.text](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.text) function and render a rotated text for the null columns.

Function for rendering/redrawing labels:

```
  function renderLabels() {
    this.series[0].points.forEach((point, i) => {
      if (point.isNull) {
        point.noDataLabel = this.renderer.text('No data', 0, -9e9).attr({
          rotation: 90,
          zIndex: 99
        }).add()
      }
    })

    redrawLabels.call(this)
}

function redrawLabels() {
  this.series[0].points.forEach(point => {
    if (point.noDataLabel) {
      point.noDataLabel.attr({
        x: point.series.group.translateX + point.plotX,
        y: this.plotTop + this.plotHeight - 80
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Attach functions on load and redraw events, and map data:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
          load: renderLabels,
          redraw: redrawLabels
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: data.map(v => v === -1 ? null : v)
    }]
});
```

#### Example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/n3nuhvL7/

[image: no data label]